# Scaling the width of a div with set "display: inline-block" parameter according to div's content length

Tags: html, css, width, display

I want to make an animation scaling the width of a div from 0% to 100% **of div's content**. I can't use px to set the dimensions of the div in keyframes, because thanks to `display: inline-block` div's dimensions changes depending on the length of the text inside the div. I have to use percentage then.

The problem is that the percentage relates to the width of the site, not the width of the div with a text. So during the animation div expands to achive 100% of site's width and after that adapts itself to the text lenght.

How to avoid expanding the width of the div to 100% of the site and animate only the text based div's width?

Here is my code:

```css
  .expanding_div {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: rozwiniecie-nakladka4 700ms ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 750ms;
}

@keyframes rozwiniecie-nakladka4 {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="expanding_div">Adam Nowak i Jan Kowalski</div>
```

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mihel/c0r2afv1/11/) has the same code exposed here.

EDIT:

**Can I use `getBoundingClientRect()` to somehow get the size of the div and use the size to animate keyframes? If so - how to do it properly?**

Comment: How big is the div? 100%?

Comment: The div adapts it's width to the text lenght. I use "display: inline-block" parameter so I don't know the width and it can change each time I change the text. But each time animation runs it has to scale from 0 to 100% of div's actual size (not the device size).